# Not able to generate correct AWS signature in Google App script

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, signature, aws-service-catalog

I am trying to access image rekognition service of AWS using google-App-script, for this, I am trying to generate an AWS signature for API call, but response showing an error message.

`{"__type":"InvalidSignatureException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}`

when I am trying with postman using authorization (AWS signature) it is working fine.

below is my google app script code in which I am calling the main function

```
function main(){
    var headers=AwsHeader_('ListCollections');

  var t=UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", {
      method: "POST",
      muteHttpExceptions:true,
    headers:headers
    });

  Logger.log("======>>"+t);
}


function hexSignature(signature){
    var signatureStr = '';
  Logger.log(signature.length);

    for (i = 0; i < signature.length; i++) {
      var byte = signature[i];
      Logger.log("byte"+byte);
      if (byte < 0)
        byte += 256;
      var byteStr = byte.toString(16);
      // Ensure we have 2 chars in our byte, pad with 0
      if (byteStr.length == 1) byteStr = '0'+byteStr;
      signatureStr += byteStr;

      Logger.log("signatureStr"+signatureStr);
    }  
  return signatureStr;
}


function get_signature(datestamp){

  var secret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var region="us-east-1";
  var service="rekognition";


  var kdate = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, datestamp, "AWS4"+secret);
  var kregion = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, region, kdate);
  var kservice = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, service, kregion);
  var ksigning = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, "aws4_request", kservice);

  var signature=hexSignature(ksigning);
  return signature;

}

function AwsHeader_(service){

  var header={};
  var date=new Date();

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
  var onlydate=Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT", "yyyyMMdd")


  var sign=get_signature(onlydate);

  header['Authorization']="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXXXX/"+onlydate+"/us-east-1/rekognition/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=cache-control;content-length;content-type;host;postman-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature="+sign;
  header['X-Amz-Date']=formattedDate;
  header['Content-Type']="application/x-amz-json-1.1";
  header['X-Amz-Target']="RekognitionService."+service;
    return header;
}
```

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong in the code, or it is the wrong method of generating the signature, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing hashed data as key to hash again returns incorrect results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795984/passing-hashed-data-as-key-to-hash-again-returns-incorrect-results)

Comment: @TheMaster . i am getting answer in 15,-31,-93,98,18,-121,-58,35,18,103,94,-40,-3,58,45,59,-49,-123,-122,5,-69,-55,94,-71,27,-11,-25,17,-112,78,-27,53 format not as shown in solution above